# Formatting issue with OrderedDict

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm looking to have my 5th column reported without duplicate value. So I used OrderedDict in the following code:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
with open(notmatch) as infile, open (two, 'w') as outfile:
    reader = csv.reader(infile, delimiter='\t')
    writer = csv.writer(outfile, delimiter='\t')
    for gg, poss, codee, ref, alt, *rest in reader:
        gg = int (gg)
        poss = int(poss)
        cls = ref + alt
        clss = list(OrderedDict.fromkeys(cls))
        writer.writerow([gg, poss, codee, d[gg][poss-1], clss] + rest)
```

This gives me output for the 5th column."clss" as the following:

```
['A','B','C']
['G','A','T']
['G','A']
['T']
```

The output I wanted was this:

```
A,B,C
G,A,T
G,A
T
```

What change should I make to have the above output (without brackets and apostrophes)? Please help me!

Comment: Add `clss` to the first list instead of storing it inside of it: `[gg, poss, codee, d[gg][poss-1]] + clss + rest`

Comment: I ended up using join function. Thanks for help though!

Answer (score 1):

I hope this helps:

```
for l in [['A','B','C'],['G','A','T'],['G','A'],['T']]:
    print ",".join(l)
```

Outputs:

```
A,B,C                                                                                                          

G,A,T                                                                                                          

G,A                                                                                                            

T
```

I believe that in your code that would look like:

```
for l in [[gg, poss, codee, d[gg][poss-1], clss] + rest]:
    writer.writerow(",".join(l) )
```